# error when creating an object in php

Tags: php

hey guys i just installed wamp server on my computer , but when i do some php on it i have an error when i creat just a simple new object here is the code

```
 <?php
      class foo {
      function affichage () {
      echo 'xxxx';
      }
      $display = new foo();
      $display -> affichage();
      }
          ?>
```

and the error is

> ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
>   ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$display' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\wamp\www\new 4.php on line 6.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have put procedural code in the middle of a class declaration. Simply don't do that.

Procedural code goes in functions or out in the middle of open space:

```
<?php
class foo {
   function affichage() {
      echo 'xxxx';
   }
}

$display = new foo();
$display->affichage();
?>
```

Your PHP book tells you where to write procedural code, *and so many other handy useful tips*. I can't help but recommend in the strongest possible terms that you read it.